# Change variable on mobile size

Tags: javascript

I have a variable I am trying to change when the screen size is smaller than 768px, my navbar gets smaller at that point so the offset on my smooth scroll link is different.

```
function scrollToID(id, speed){
    var offSet = 100;
    var targetOffset = $(id).offset().top - offSet;
    $('html,body').animate({scrollTop:targetOffset}, speed);
}
```

I am having trouble figuring this one out, I was going to try using an if statement with `if(width >= 768)` but I believe this isn't going to work.

How can I change the variable offSet on widths smaller than 768px?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var offSet = 100;
if($(window).width() <= 768){
     offset = // new value;
}
```

using [`jQuery.width`](https://api.jquery.com/width/).

Comment: Ah thats perfect I got pretty close, but this is exact! Thank you!